# VSTO Addin Form Closing Handler

Tags: c#, forms, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a VSTO addin for outlook 2013.  I'm trying to register an event with an event handler for a Form closing event.

Here is my code from class Form1:

```
    public delegate void MyEventHandler();
    private event MyEventHandler Closing;

    private void OtherInitialize()
    {
        this.Closing += new MyEventHandler(this.Form1_Closing);
    }
```

Also from class Form1:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OtherInitialize();
    }

    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Not sure what to put here to make the application exit completely
        // Looking for something similar to Pytthon's sys.exit() or
        // Applicaton.Exit() in Forms Applicatons, I tried
        // Applicaton.Exit() it did not work
    }
```

When I run this I get the error and warning:

The warning:

```
Form1.Closing hides inherited member System.Windows.Forms.Form.Closing.  Use the new keyword if hiding was intended
```

The error:

```
No overload for Form1_Closing matches delegate System.EventHandler
```

What do these errors/warnings mean?  How can I properly register the Form1_Closing event handler for when the form is closed with either the X button or form.Close()   Right now I'm able to call form.Close() but it doesn't seem to trigger the Form1_Closing event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to declare the Closing event because the parent class provides the event out of the box. Moreover, you can simply set the event handler without declaring the delegate class (latest .net versions):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    OtherInitialize();
}

private void OtherInitialize()
{
    Closing += Form1_Closing;
}

private void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Not sure what to put here to make the application exit completely
    // Looking for something similar to Pytthon's sys.exit() or
    // Applicaton.Exit() in Forms Applicatons, I tried
    // Applicaton.Exit() it did not work
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing this.Closing += new ClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_Closing) is that any different?  Will thtey catch pressing the X and pressing Cancel (DialogResult.Cancel)?  I'm pretty sure X will be captured but what about Cancel?

Comment: The [Closing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event is fired as the form is being closed. When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are released and the form is disposed. If you cancel this event, the form remains opened. To cancel the closure of a form, set the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs passed to your event handler to true.

Comment: When a form is displayed as a modal dialog box, clicking the Close button (the button with an X at the upper-right corner of the form) causes the form to be hidden and the DialogResult property to be set to DialogResult.Cancel. You can override the value assigned to the DialogResult property when the user clicks the Close button by setting the DialogResult property in an event handler for the Closing event of the form.